# How to detect if user has entered any data as a console input

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, user-input

Is there a way to find out if the user has entered any data in the terminal window without having to use the blocking `stdin`.

I am implementing a chat client using twisted python and the client code should display messages from other connected clients. As soon as the client enters a message and hits enter, i want it to run an event driven loop, which sends the message to the server, which then broadcasts it to every other client.

In short, I am trying to look for a way to detect when the user hits ENTER or enters some text in the terminal without having to block the program.

UPDATE: Client code so far..

```
class MyClientProtocol( protocol.Protocol ):
    def sendData( self ):
            message = raw_input( 'Enter Message: ' )
            if message and ( message != "quit()" ):
                logging.debug( " ...Sending %s ...", message )
                self.transport.write( str( message ) )
            else:
                self.transport.loseConnection()

    def connectionMade( self ):
        print "Connection made to server!"

    def dataReceived( self, msg ):
        print msg
        self.sendData()

class MyClientFactory( protocol.ClientFactory ):
    protocol = MyClientProtocol
    clientConnectionLost = clientConnectionFailed = lambda self, connector, reason: reactor.stop()

reactor.connectTCP( HOST, PORT, MyClientFactory() )
reactor.run()
```

This code only currently only accepts the user input after receiving something from back from the server, as i am calling `sendData` in `dataReceived`. Any suggestions on how i can make this pick up user entered data, plus also keep getting data from the server?

Comment: You probably want to look at the [`select`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) module.

Comment: Examples of [select](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/select/) and [asynchat](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/asynchat/index.html#module-asynchat) might give a flavour of what's possible.

Comment: @Bakuriu: You can't `select` on `stdin` on Windows, can you? (Of course the OP didn't say this has to be cross-platform, but I generally assume that end-user-focused apps need to be.)

Comment: I am trying to implement it on Unix. @Bakuriu, I have used `select` with sockets earlier to implement a chat server-client. Can you give me a small snippet or a link to some documentation where i can see an example of `select` being used with `twisted`.

Comment: You really don't want to throw a `select` event loop into the middle of the `twisted` event loop. You get two reactors fighting over ownership of the same thread. You can make the twisted reactor drive the `select` reactor once each time through the loop, put a 0 timeout on the `select` loop and a short-ish timeout on the `twisted` loop (so you're busy-waiting, but "not too badly"), but really, just don't if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already using Twisted, they have plugins for hooking almost *anything* into the event loop.

But for `stdin`, you don't even need a plugin; it's built in. One of the stock examples even shows exactly what you're trying to do. It's the one named [`stdin.py`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/core/examples/stdin.py).

Answer (score 0):

I also recently played around with this. What I did was just start a separate thread (using the [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module) that was waiting for user input, and the main thread was receiving and printing broadcast messages, like:

```
def collect_input():
   while True:
      msg = raw_input()
      handle(msg) # you'll need to implement this

# in client code
import threading
t = threading.Thread(target=collect_input)
t.start()
```

I'm not sure if it's a good idea, but it was the first that came to my mind and it seemed to work.

Note: I wasn't using `Twisted`, just `sockets`. As you can see from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14884476/1258041), you don't need to implement it with Twisted.